# How to prompt user to input a number to get size of array. Then sort array using bubble sort method

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, bubble-sort

Haven't practiced Java in a long while so any help would be appreciated.

For the class project, we have to create a program that prompts the user to input a number and creates the size of an array. After input, we are to show the list of numbers before it is sorted and a list after it has been sorted using the bubble sort algorithm.

Here is what I have so far. I know I'm missing a chunk of code so that I can get the list to print both before and after sorting, but I'm lost.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Part1BubbleSort  
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    //int temp = 0;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int z = scan.nextInt();
    int [] array = new int[z];
    System.out.print("Please enter a number to create array."+"\n");
    z = scan.nextInt();

    //Bubble Sort
    for(int i = array.length-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<i; j++)
        {
            if(array[j] > array[j+1])
            {
                int temp = array[j];
                array[j] = array[j+1];
                array[j+1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you are only taking two numbers as input, first one is size which is ok but second z is never used. if you want user to input array elements also then you should put `array[i]=scan.nextInt(); ` in a for loop where i:0->z. to print an array you can use `Arrays.toString(array);`

Comment: Great! Thanks for pointing that out... especially the two inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do as follows:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class BubbleTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a number to create array."+"\n");
        int z = scan.nextInt();
        int [] array = new int[z];
        // Randomly generating array elements

        for(int i =0; i<z; i++){
            array[i]=new Random().nextInt();
        }
      //  z = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Unsorted:");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));


        //Bubble Sort
        for(int i = array.length-1; i>=0; i--)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<i; j++)
            {
                if(array[j] > array[j+1])
                {
                    int temp = array[j];
                    array[j] = array[j+1];
                    array[j+1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("sorted:");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
    }

}
```

Comment: Huge help. Thank you! I'm going to attempt having the code generate random elements, but this definitely pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: For generating Random number, you could use Random class. For Example, Random r=new Random(); array[i]=r.nextInt();

Comment: Great, thank you! It took me a while to get it working. Before I saw your update I kept making the mistake of seting the array size (z) into the random scan range. For example: 
array[i]= new Random().nextInt(z); 
Silly mistake. I fixed it to max out at 1000. Thanks again!